# How does pkg-config work in RPM specfiles?

Tags: compiling, rpm, packaging, rpm-spec, pkg-config

In some RPM specfiles, I see lines like:

```
BuildRequires: pkgconfig(ice)
BuildRequires: pkgconfig(libnotify)
BuildRequires: pkgconfig(libssl)
...
```

I am not very familiar with pkgconfig but I understand that some installed libraries have a corresponding `.pc` file which describes them. I have 2 questions:

1. Is this only used for dynamic libraries?
2. How does RPM handle the above in a situation where ice, libnotify, and libssl are NOT found on the system currently or where they are found but there is no corresponding `.pc` file?

Answer (score 0):

1. I don’t know if any RPMs *use* this in practice, but `pkg-config` handles static libraries too.
2. If the build requirements aren’t met, the RPM build will fail.

Comment: Oh I see, and I assume that yum & dnf go and fetch the dependencies prior to running rpmbuild so I as a user don't actually get a missing dependency error?